# SHBrowseForFolder: inactive controls

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I have dialog window with button (IDC_browse). 
SHBrowseForFolder shows dialog box that enables the user to select a Shell folder.
But I can't use scroll and buttons Ok and Cancel. Even clicking doesn't work!
Please tell me what is wrong. 
Declaration:

```
BROWSEINFO   bi;
LPITEMIDLIST  pidl;
```

In CALLBACK function

```
case IDC_browse:   
 ZeroMemory(&bi, sizeof(bi));  
 bi.hwndOwner = hWnd; 
 bi.pszDisplayName = szDisplayName; 
 bi.lpszTitle = TEXT("Text"); 
 bi.ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS;  
 pidl = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi); 
 break;
```

P.S. MS Visual Studio 2010, win32 api project. Developing on Windows 7 (x64)

Comment: Did you call CoInitializeEx()?  Look in the Output window for shell extensions getting loaded that might mess up your program.

Comment: Hmm.. I didn't call CoInitializeEx().